# How to execute multiple-line selection in do-file editor of Stata?

Tags: stata

Does anyone know how to use the "execute selection" function in the do-file editor of Stata for code that spans multiple lines?
Currently I can't find a way to do this without using the #delimit ; system which requires repeating "delimit ;" at the beginning of every block I want to run.
Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: If you problem is just typing `#delimit ;` all the time, you can add it to profile.do  (see `help profile`)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you might be understanding the `#delimit ;` command wrongly: this is useful when you are coding a do-file to execute it in its entirety afterwards. I also assume that you are using Stata 11, since previous versions behave differently (if I recall well, Stata 10 SE for Mac does not support `//` comments and delimiting, for example).

If you are executing only a fraction of the code, use `///` at the end of a line to continue its command on the next one.

Basic example (that will clear any open data, so beware):

```
sysuse lifeexp, clear
sc lexp safewater, ///
mlab(country);
```

This should run flawlessly even if you execute the `sysuse` command and the `sc` (`scatter`) commands separately. The `sc` command has the `mlab` option (to add labels to the data points) on a different line, but both lines will be interpreted as only one command due to the `///` indication.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that `///` only applies to .do and .ado files.  It doesn't work from the command box in interactive Stata.  This is all documented in the .pdf manual "16.1.3 Long lines in do-files"