# Stata delimit in command line

Tags: comments, stata

I am working on a .do file created by someone else.  This person used a semicolon delimiter in the entire file.  I am trying to go through this file and see what is going on.  I like to do this by selecting a portion of the code and hitting the "Execute Selection (do)" button.  However, the delimiter seems to be messing up this.  Are there any workarounds for me?

Comment: This shouldn't cause any problems...have you set your delimiter by `#delimit ;` before you run any of the selections?

Comment: I cannot use ``#delimit ;`` in the command line.  If I run a selection from the .do file, I think I must have ``#delimit ;`` as part of the selection, which isn't going to happen as it would be super annoying to always include this at the beginning of every selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your do-file looks like this:

```
#delimit ;
set obs 
        10 ;
gen x = _n ;
gen y = x^2 ;
gen z = x
         ^3;
```

Anytime you highlight a selection and press "Execute selection (do)", Stata creates a temporary, self-contained do-file, with default delimit at `cr` and runs that:

```
"When a do-file begins execution, the delimiter is automatically set to 
carriage return, even if it was called from another do-file that set the
delimiter to semicolon."
```

It does not sequentially run those commands from the console. Therefore, if you select the first 2 commands in the do-file above, the temporary do-file includes a call to `#delimit` whereas if you selected the last 2 commands, the temporary do-file would not have this call and would throw a syntax error for two line commands.

One solution could be to copy-paste selections to a fresh do-file that just had the `#delimit` command at the beginning, and then run that.

You could also write a script to rid your do-file of semicolons. If a line does not end in a semicolon, then append the next line to the end of the current line, and check this line again. Depending on how complex the syntax is in your do-file, this would be more or less difficult.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the semicolons, but the file is very long.  I found something similar to your suggestion of creating the fresh do-file and copying and pasting.  It suggested to create a profile.do file and include ``#delimit ;`` in it.  Would this work?  I found this suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985751/how-to-execute-multiple-line-selection-in-do-file-editor-of-stata).  If it would work, where would I store the profile.do file and would I need to delete it when working on other do files not involving ``delimit`` stuff?

Comment: You could try that but I don't think it will work. `profile.do` gets run at the beginning of every Stata session, not when a new do-file is run. As soon as you run a do-file that does not have the `#delimit` command in it, it is by default set to `cr`.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for all the help.  It sounds like the best thing to do is to replace everything and avoid using the delimit in the future.

Comment: That seems best in this case. The `;` delimiter can be helpful, especially if you are writing very long commands, and causes problems only in the "execute selection"...so basically pick one of delimiter/execute selection that you want more

Answer (score 1):

Another option is comment out the lines you have already ran by enclosing them with `/* */` and to use `exit;` where you want to stop. You do have to be a little careful with local macros.